# Using SQL Server view in Microsoft Query

Tags: sql-server, excel, microsoft-query

I have a view in SQL Server named `item_movement`, now I want to query using Microsoft Query in Excel:

```
select * from item_movement
```

But I'm getting this error - why? Is it possible to use Microsoft Query for querying views?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue had to use the keyword

`use mydbname` before query

Comment: That's just a reference issue then. You can probably also use `select * from mydbname.dbo.item_movement` which directly references the view from that database without changing the database context like `USE mydbname` does. For future reference, a screenshot of the entire query window you're using in Excel is probably helpful (in addition to the query text).